# How can I make a dynamic width for elements based on the screen size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```css
.container{
  border:1px solid;
  width: 70%;
}

.el {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="el">one</div>
  <div class="el">two</div>
  <div class="el">three</div>
  <div class="el">four</div>
  <div class="el">five</div>
  <div class="el">six</div>
  <div class="el">seven</div>
  <div class="el">eight</div>
</div>
```

Please run the code snippet above, click on *Full page* button and resize the page. I want to divide `div.container` to equal parts.

So if there are three elements (`div.el`) in a row, then the `width` of them should be `33%`. If two elements in a row, then the `width` should be `50%`.

How can I do that? Noted that I don't want to use any framework like Bootstrap.

Comment: the best solution is to use bootstrap. it will save you a lot of time.

Comment: The only way would be to use CSS Grid with appropriate fallbacks.
Otherwise, your width decides how many elements you have per row, not vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Example of use :

```
// Foo's original width is 100%
.foo {
    width: 100%
}

@media screen and (max-width: 100px){
    // Foo's width will be 50% when the view's width is below 100px
    .foo {
        width: 50%
    }
}

... OR ...

@media screen and (min-width: 100px){
    // Foo's width will be 50% when the view's width is over 100px
    .foo {
        width: 50%
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using css flex-box. Apply `display:flex;` property for your container and manipulate the items `.el` inside that container using `flex-grow: 1;` to stretch them out to remaining width of screen and share the space accordingly.

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  width: 70%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.el {
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="el">one</div>
  <div class="el">two</div>
  <div class="el">three</div>
  <div class="el">four</div>
  <div class="el">five</div>
  <div class="el">six</div>
  <div class="el">seven</div>
  <div class="el">eight</div>
</div>
```

CodePen example: https://codepen.io/CapySloth/pen/LLBgEB

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container{
  border:1px solid;
  width: 70%;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.el {
  border: 1px solid red;
  min-width: auto;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="el">one</div>
  <div class="el">two</div>
  <div class="el">three</div>
  <div class="el">four</div>
  <div class="el">five</div>
  <div class="el">six</div>
  <div class="el">seven</div>
  <div class="el">eight</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given I did this myself, I'm almost totally certain the best way is with flexbox's `flex-wrap` to make the items overflow and `flex-grow` to make them take up as much space as possible.

```
<div id="cont">
  <div>asdf</div>
  <div>asdf</div>
  <div>asdf</div>
  <div>asdf</div>
  <div>asdf</div>
  <div>asdf</div>
  <div>asdf</div>
  <div>asdf</div>
  <div>asdf</div>
  <div>asdf</div>
</div>
```

```
#cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#cont div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1Lpwfon5/), or on [my own website](http://jhak-launchpad.herokuapp.com/).

Note that this isn't a grid system, so the last row isn't going to obey the same column width as all the previous (full ones). If you want the cells to spill over if the space is available and also look like a grid given the last line, you'll need to tack on some JavaScript.